# Is it normal for LVL to deny valid licenses?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I am getting occasional complaints from my users that my paid application is failing the Android Market Licence Verification Library check.  I cannot post code samples but my code is very similar to the  sample in the LVL doc,  with a little custom obfuscation,  plus it works for 99% of my users. And I checked that the complaining users did indeed buy my app.

I'm seriously thinking of dropping the LVL altogether because my app was hacked in a day anyway and the LVL seems like a joke. Is it known to fail periodically or is the problem definitely in my app?

Sorry I cannot provide more info but I'll try to answer any questions I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been suffering from the same problem for a while now as have many others. It seems to be a problem that google is aware of ( https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs ) but no solution, or any information really as yet.

We send out the following which has helped a few users to clear the problem:

> Licencing/ ox1 Error: Can be fixed by either by clearing the
>   data and cache from the Google Play Store App or/and the Download
>   Manager app. Another potential is to play the game in Flight Mode
>   initially.

I suspect there is a way to use LVL and it work as expected but for now it seems like 1% of users will be stuck.

Comment: Ugh. What are we supposed to say? "Dear users, please clear the data and cache from your Google Play Store App so it doesn't report false negatives anymore"?  I already went ahead and implemented my own license validation. In a way it is better than LVL because the hackers don't know to look for it.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't mean to sound ungrateful for your answer. My rant was directed at Google, not you.

Comment: Not a problem. We actually tell users to clear the cache in the 'this game is not licensed' popup